# How to add friend in 5 in a Row Gomoku - Miniclip

Tags: gomoku

Today I played 18 games against a player from Brazil, and at the end the score was 9-9 :)).

I was wondering how can I add this player as a friend to see when is online and play again with him in the future?

Answer (score 1):

Since the game is played on Miniclip, you can add him or her to your friends list on Miniclip, but not specifically for 5 in a Row Gomoku.

Under your username with your awards, etc. there should be a "Search for Player" tool. Enter your friend's name, and then click on the one that is him or her once the site shows you a list of players with names similar to what you typed in. Click on his username, and his profile page will have a button to add him as a friend.

Comment: I cant find it., please attach a screenshot to see where is this option, thanks